# Add IAuthorization handler to Autofac

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, autofac

I'm creating some authorization policies for ASP.NET Core and obviously I've created some AuthorizationHandlers.

Now, authorization mechanism requires authorization handlers to be resolvable. I'm using Autofac instead of built-in mechanism so here's how I'm trying to achieve it:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AuthorizationHandler<>))
    .As<IAuthorizationHandler>()
    .OnActivating(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x.Instance))
    .AutoActivate();
```

My understanding is:

1. I register types from executing assembly (where my handlers reside)
2. That inherit from AuthorizationHandler<>
3. Register them as IAuthorizationHandler.

I've added OnActivating and AutoActivate event for the purpose of debugging. As you can see I'm logging when there's an activation.

But my logging doesn't execute even once. It seems that Autofac is not able to find my authorization handlers. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted looks perfect. Anyway, I've tested it and works for me as expected (including auto-activate). Environment: NET Core 2.1, Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection 4.2.2.

I'm 99,9% sure the problem is elsewhere. I can think of the following:

- there's no non-abstract class extending AuthorizationHandler<TRequirement> in the executing assembly or
- more likely, your Autofac container doesn't get build.

Does your *Startup.ConfigureServices* method look like this?

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // standard ASP.NET Core setup like
    services.AddMvc(...)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AuthorizationHandler<>))
        .As<IAuthorizationHandler>()
        .OnActivating(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x.Instance))
        .AutoActivate();

    builder.Populate(services);

    var container = builder.Build();
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

Comment: Ehh, silly me. Authorization handlers were in different assembly. Code is perfect as you say.

Answer (score 3):

I must have 50 reputation to comment, so I will answer

@Adam Simon's answer is correct for AuthorizationHandlers, but it's not registering resource based resource handlers correctly.

You have to add another `RegisterAssemblyTypes` invocation with one different line

```
.AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AuthorizationHandler<,>)) // notice comma in generic type
```

(notice comma in generic type)

Working version for two types of AuthorizationHandlers is:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AuthorizationHandler<>))
    .As<IAuthorizationHandler>()
    .OnActivating(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x.Instance))
    .AutoActivate();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(AuthorizationHandler<,>))
    .As<IAuthorizationHandler>()
    .OnActivating(x => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x.Instance))
    .AutoActivate();
```